# Using linear index to map to 4D array

Tags: arrays, cuda

I am just starting with CUDA programming and I am bewildered by the speeds compared to normal CPUs. However, I am now getting running in a simple logical consideration. I am in device code, and I have 4D to inspect. I made a **constant** variable and I use atomicAdd to add through each iteration through the device code.

```
//get global counter
int global_index = atomicAdd(&counter, 1);
```

I then consider a 4D volume, and I attempt to map the linear index to the 4D volume. I know that for 2D ad 3D, there is an effective way of converting from 1D index to 3D mapping. However, I do not know how this methodology expands into a higher dimension.

```
int x = gcfg->dimlen.x;
int y = gcfg->dimlen.y / x;
int z = gcfg->dimlen.z / gcfg->dimlen.y;
int photons = numberofphotons[1];
```

Here is my 4 dimensions' lengths. So, to reiterate the problem I am having: I have an index that I want to map to a 4D array with lengths specified by the above 4 dimensions (x,y,z,numberofphotons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I've understood the meanings of the variables in your question, but following code is for the case where first dimension length(`x`) == second dimension length(`y`) == third dimension length(`z`) == `4`. It converts linear index `i` into indices for each dimension: `first_index`, `second_index`, `third_index`, `fourth_index`.

```
int main()
{
    int x = 4;
    int y = 4;
    int z = 4;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        int fourth_index = i / (x * y * z);
        int third_index = i % (x * y * z) / (x * y);
        int second_index = i % (x * y * z) % (x * y) / x;
        int first_index = i % (x * y * z) % (x * y) % x;

        printf("%d: (%d, %d, %d, %d)\n", i, first_index, second_index, third_index, fourth_index);
    }
}
```

Or you can go the other way round.

```
int main()
{
    int x = 4;
    int y = 4;
    int z = 4;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        int first_index = i % x;
        int second_index = i / x % y;
        int third_index = i / x / y % z;
        int fourth_index = i / x / y / z;

        printf("%d: (%d, %d, %d, %d)\n", i, first_index, second_index, third_index, fourth_index);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!